# Circular primes

Tags: code-golf, primes

Given a number determine if it is a circular prime.

A circular prime is a prime where if you rotate the digits you still get prime numbers.
1193 is circular prime because 1931 and 9311 and 3119 are all primes.

```
Input:          Output:
1193            circular
11939           circular
1456            nothing
193939          circular
1111111         nothing
7               circular
23              nothing
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: I don't think this should have the code-challenge tag.

Comment: @Cruncher Wouldn't solving such problem in shortest possible code require creative thinking? If it is not code-challenge then I will gladly remove it, just assumed it to be challenge.

Comment: Not a big deal, but they're sort of disjoint. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-challenge/info "A code challenge is a competition for creative ways to solve a programming puzzle for an objective criterion other than code size."

Comment: @Cruncher sorry about that. Thanks for clarifying it for me :)

Comment: -1 You stated: "Shortest code wins" but awarded the check to a submission that was 4 times as long as the shortest submitted!

Comment: @DavidCarraher I asked for specific output. I do not see the shortest answer provide such output. Try running some programs and see if input and output matches for what is requested.

Comment: You must be kidding.

Comment: @DavidCarraher please do enlighten me which is the answer whose's code if I copy paste and run will yield the output on the given input specified above?

Comment: My own code returns True if a number is circular, False if a number is not circular.  I find that a reasonable alternative to "circular" and "nothing".  The shorter solution in J appears to follow the same Boolean convention (True, False).

Comment: @DavidCarraher Some problems on this site require specific output.  This is one.  Deal with it and stop whining. "Oh, poor me, my output `99,98,97...` is equivalent to the lyrics of '99 bottles of beer on the wall' but it wasn't an accepted answer!"

Comment: @Boothby.  Bad example.  "99 bottles of beer on the wall" is all about crafting a specific output, the lyrics of a song.  The present example is advertised a test of circularity of a number: "Given a number determine if it is a circular prime."  Example output was given. But it was not stated (nor should it have been, in my view) that that specific format is required).

Comment: @DavidCarraher, It most certainly is stated. despite your wishes to the contrary.  Look at the question, and see "Input" and "Output".  This is a 'compound question': solve a challenge *and* format the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 47 characters

```
:s,,{)s/(+~:P{(.P\%}do(},!"nothing
circular"n/=
```

Input must be given on STDIN without trailing newline ([online example](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjExOTMiCgo6cywseylzLygrfjpQeyguUFwlfWRvKH0sISJub3RoaW5nCmNpcmN1bGFyIm4vPQ%3D%3D&run=true)).

Comment: It's beautiful :)

Answer (score 8):

## J, 47 chars (w/ formatted output)

```
('nothing';'circular'){~*/1&p:".(|."0 1~i.&#)":
```

## J, 23 chars (boolean only)

```
*/1&p:".(|."0 1~i.&#)":
```

`":` is a string conversion; `i.&#` produces a range of integers [0,len), and `|."0 1~` is a rotation of the string by each successive integer of the range.

`".` converts the list of rotations back into numbers, `1&p:` converts the list of numbers into booleans (i.e. "prime?" predicate), and `*/` is a multiply reduce over the booleans (i.e. and).

Comment: Wow I really like this :) nicely done

Comment: Add an `{'nothing';'circular'` and beat the Python submission :)

Comment: @marinus Done, though it really hurts my sense of aesthetics... The interface between the human and the program is always the least fun to code.

Comment: Months after the fact, I finally just realized I could replace `[:i.#` with `i.&#`, which was bugging me at the time... [L'esprit_de_l'escalier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'esprit_de_l'escalier). Take that, GolfScript!

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 106 chars

```
p=input();n=`p`
for i in n:
 n=n[1:]+n[0];e=2
 while`e`!=n:p*=int(n)%e;e+=1
print'cniortchuilnagr'[p<1::2]
```

Comment: I see what you did there with the answer :) very clever

Comment: Oh man! I just did mine in Python and I came up with "cniortchuilnagr" independently.

Comment: Whoa! I got the idea from http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/406/9395

Comment: You can make this both shorter and correct if you use `for i in n`... otherwise, this will fail to rule out certain primes with more than 10 digits.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica <s>62</s> 61

```
f@s_ := And @@ PrimeQ[FromDigits@StringRotateLeft[s, #] & /@ Range@9]
```

**Usage**

```
f["1193"]
```

> True

```
f["11939"]
```

> True

```
f["1456"]
```

> False

```
f["193939"]
```

> True

```
f["1111111"]
```

> False

```
f["7"]
```

> True

```
f["23"]
```

> False

Comment: You can use `FromDigits` instead of `ToExpression`.

Comment: I had no idea that `FromDigits` could handle strings!

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <s>110</s> 109 chars

```
require'mathn'
x=gets.chop.split''
puts (0..x.size).all?{|n|x.rotate(n).join.to_i.prime?}?:circular:'nothing'
```

Comment: You can shorten 1 character by using Symbol instead of String for `:circular`.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <s>75</s> 64

```
And@@PrimeQ[FromDigits/@NestList[RotateLeft,IntegerDigits@#,9]]&
```

Comment: You can save a few characters by using `RotateRight` or `RotateLeft` to rotate the digits.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: Thanks, it saves quite a few, actually. How at one point I must have thought my elaborate `Part` trick would be shorter, I find most puzzling, but even now, you're still a good three characters ahead.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 139

```
a=scan()
p=0
A=nchar(a)
S=substr
for(i in 1:A){b=as.integer(paste0(S(a,i+1,A),S(a,1,i)));p=p+!sum(!b%%1:b)<3}
c('nothing','circular')[!p+1]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python3.3, 160C

```
def m():
 s=input()
 r=range
 for i in r(len(s)):
  a=int(s)
  if all(a%i for i in r(2,a)):return 0
  s=s[1:]+s[:1]
 return 1 
print("cniortchuilnagr"[m()::2])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Smalltalk, 195 chars

```
[:x|r:=[:n|(n\\10)*(10 raisedTo:n log floor)+(n//10)].s:=OrderedCollection with:x.[(m:=r value:s last)=x]whileFalse:[s add:m].^(s allSatisfy:[:each|each isPrime])ifTrue:['circular']ifFalse:['nothing']]
```

formatted

```
[:x|
  r:=[:n|(n\\10)*(10 raisedTo:n log floor)+(n//10)].
  s:=OrderedCollection with:x.
  [(m:=r value:s last)=x]whileFalse:[s add:m].
  ^(s allSatisfy:[:each|each isPrime])ifTrue:['circular']ifFalse:['nothing']]
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 53

```
'nothing' 'circular'[1+^/{⌊/⍵|⍨1↓⍳⍵-1}¨⍎¨{⍵⌽∆}¨⍳⍴∆←⍞]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Would obviously be a hell of a lot shorter without the unnecessarily strict output requirement, which accounts for more than half the score here.

```
ÆìéX jÃ×g`Í(ˆg circÔ³`¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xuzpWCBqw9dnYM0oiGcgY2lyY9SzYLg&input=WwoxMTkzCjExOTM5CjE0NTYKMTkzOTM5CjExMTExMTEKNwoyMwpdLW1S) (includes all test cases)

```
ÆìéX jÃ×g`...`¸     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                   :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 ì                  :   Convert U to digit array
  éX                :   Rotate right X times and convert back to integer
     j              :  Is prime?
      Ã             :End map
       ×            :Reduce by multiplication
        g           :Index into (0-based)
         `...`      :  Compressed string "circular nothing"
              ¸     :  Split on spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>22</s></sup> 19 bytes

```
?¨ÿċ◊¨¨ø±¨ΛoṗdSṀṙŀd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9odXNr//8/wqjDv8SL4peKwqjCqMO4wrHCqM6bb@G5l2RT4bmA4bmZxYBk////MTE5Mw)

-3 bytes from Jo King. (simplified using `Ṁ`)

Comment: You can simplify that last bit of logic for [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9odXNr//8/wqjDv8SL4peKwqjCqMO4wrHCqM6bb@G5l2RT4bmA4bmZxYBk////MTE5Mw)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

*<sup>-1 thanks to @ovs!</sup>*

```
gL._pP
```

Outputs `1` if a circular prime, and `0` if not! :D

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3UcvviDg/39DQ0tjAA)

This is actually my first effortful code answer in this site! **Yey!**

### How?

```
g         # Get the number of digits in the input number.
 L        # Push a list of all numbers from 1 to the length.
  ._      # For each number 'n' in the list, rotate the input to to the left n times and push a list of all outcomes.
    p     # Is each rotation a prime? If prime, convert that number to 1, else convert it to 0.
     P    # Push the product of all 1's or 0's (if a rotation is not prime, the product should be zero).
          # Print the product automatically.
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>17</strike> 16 bytes

*<sup>Again -1 thanks to @ovs!</sup>*

```
gL._pP“‹ë“si“ÒŽ“
```

This code follows the output standard suggested by the test cases. I wrote this just in case my previous answer is invalid. If it is not, please count 6B as my score!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3UcvviDgUcOcRw07D68G0sWZQOLwpKN7gdT//4aGlsYA)

### How again?

```
gL._pP              # Works just like the previous answer.
      “‹ë“          # Push the string "nothing" from the 05AB1E dictionary.
          s         # Bring back the number output again.
           i        # If the number is 1...
            “ÒŽ“    # Push the string "circular" again from the 05AB1E dictionary.
```

Thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen's tip on compressing strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/98140)! :)

*Edit:* Wow, I noticed that both of my answers are currently the shortest (during the time of writing). That is kind of ironic for a first effortful answer. That means I won!

Comment: My interpretation of the spec was the same as yours until I looked through the solutions. Pretty sure now that we _have_ to output the words in the spec and the comments on the challenge would seem to back that up.

Comment: @Shaggy Yea, but a Mathematica answer claims that it outputs "True" and "False" for output.

Comment: If you rotate the input by the input length, you still get the input. This means `gL` works instead of `g<Ý`. And for this the builtin `ā` (length range) exists.

Comment: @ovs Indeed you are right!